# Displaying the Lowest and Highest numbers in a group

Tags: java

I am working on a bit of code that puts a group of 8 numbers in acceding order, displays the highest number and the lowest number, and finally shows the difference between the highest number and the lowest number.

I believe my code works well enough to obtain all the numbers, put them in ascending order, then finally show the difference between the highest number and lowest. But I cant figure out how to show the highest number and the lowest number, or how to have my code take the highest number and subtract the lowest number.

Any help would be great!

```
    public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cnt = 0;

    int user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user7, user8 ;
    int highNum = 0;
    int lowNum = 0;
    int numberDiff = (highNum - lowNum);

    System.out.println("Please enter the game scores here: ");
    user1 = sc.nextInt();
    user2 = sc.nextInt();
    user3 = sc.nextInt();
    user4 = sc.nextInt();
    user5 = sc.nextInt();
    user6 = sc.nextInt();
    user7 = sc.nextInt();
    user8 = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; cnt!=8; i++)
    {
        if(i== user1 || i== user2 || i== user3 || i== user4 || i== user5 || i== user6 || i== user7 || i== user8)
        {
            System.out.println("\t" + i);
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The greatest diffrence in score between " +
    "the highest scoring game and the lowest scoring game is: " + numberDiff);
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn about arrays and Lists. These will allow you to store an indeterminate number of ints and not be limited to just 8.

Comment: What if the user enters `10` or `-42`?

Comment: Without knowing the smallest and largest numbers how do you say you can already find the difference between them?

Comment: your right about more than just the 8 numbers and also if the user enters a negative number. This is just supposed to help get me started in using arrays and lists, I figured starting with just 8 would be ok. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Why do you use print out a counter? Why not the numbers themselves?

Answer (score 0):

```
lowNum = user1;
highNum = user1;
for(int i = 0; cnt!=8; i++)
{
    if(i== user1 || i== user2 || i== user3 || i== user4 || i== user5 || i== user6 || i== user7 || i== user8)
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + i);
        if(i > highNum) {
            highNum = i;
        }
        if (i < lowNum)
            lowNum = i;
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

This will give you the highest number in highNum. Similarly set the lowNum to the value of user1 and keep changing whenever you find a lower number.

Setting lowNum and highNum to the first user also handles the case for negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the great info! Im still having a slight problem where it is giving me an error for using int highNum = user1; and the same for lowNum. so I tried just using 0, and that didnt give me an error but it keeps pulling 0 as the lowest number, no problem with the highest though. Thank you so much for the help!!!!